# Realm seemingly keeps resetting the database on iOS devices

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I cannot seem to figure out why or when Realm.io decides to delete the file I am storing in the documents directory. By monitoring through write events after a while the file is no longer findable.

I cannot read anything in the documents about doing any manual writes to file, but it is rather important that localStorage is persistent.

On the simulator I can fix this problem by using a URL directly on my desktop, rather than inside the simulator. This however is of course not available on iOS.

Manual writeCopy(to:_) doesn't seem to help out either.

Config:

```
let cfg = Realm.Configuration(
            fileURL: Database.baseURL(),
            inMemoryIdentifier: nil,
            syncConfiguration: nil,
            encryptionKey: _password,
            readOnly: false,
            schemaVersion: 1,
            migrationBlock: { migration, oldVersion in
            },
            deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: false,
            objectTypes: nil
        )
```

**Update #1**

Example of writing code:

```
internal func dbRow() -> MessageRow {
        let row = MessageRow()

        row.id = id
        row.state = Int(status.rawValue)
        row.remoteID = remoteID
        row.receiverID = receiver.id
        row.senderID = author.id
        row.filePath = filePath
        row.message = text
        row.timestamp = timestamp.timeIntervalSince1970
        row.burnTime = burnTime
        return row
    }

    internal func update() {
        try! Database.default.realm.write {
            Database.default.realm.add(self.dbRow(), update: true)
        }
    }

    internal func save(outGoing: Bool = false) {
        if outGoing == true {
            guard let row = receiver.row else { return }

            try! Database.default.realm.write {
                row.messages.append(self.dbRow())
            }
            return
        }
        guard let row = author.row else { return }

        try! Database.default.realm.write {
            row.messages.append(self.dbRow())
        }
    }
```

MessageRow.swift:

```
class MessageRow: Object {
    dynamic var id:            Int = 0
    dynamic var message:    String = ""
    dynamic var state:         Int = 0
    dynamic var senderID:      Int = 0
    dynamic var receiverID:    Int = 0
    dynamic var remoteID:      Int = 0
    dynamic var burnTime:      Int = 0
    dynamic var timestamp:  Double = 0
    dynamic var filePath:  String? = nil

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

`receiver.row` Contains a UserRow instance fetched from Realm before, with the definition being as follows:

```
internal class UserRow: Object {
    dynamic var id:       Int = 0

    dynamic var firstName: String = ""
    dynamic var lastName:  String = ""
    dynamic var infix:     String = ""
    dynamic var clinic:    String = ""
    dynamic var avatarURL: String = ""
    dynamic var clinicalFocus: String = ""
    dynamic var position:  String = ""
    dynamic var lastOnline:  Date = Date()
    dynamic var publicKey:   Data = Data()
    dynamic var isPending:   Bool = false

    var messages: List<MessageRow> = List<MessageRow>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}


Optional(UserRow {
    id = 2;
    firstName = Helpdesk;
    lastName = MDLinking;
    infix = ;
    clinic = ;
    avatarURL = https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mdlinking-dev/2016/10/21/images/f1fb4e96-7767-4e99-b3e0-7a7c8b9dca04.png;
    clinicalFocus = ;
    position = ;
    lastOnline = 2016-12-15 16:35:01 +0000;
    publicKey = <93ce6666 7ca47759 184915ec a5efb4df 1b814309 06421b0b — 32 total bytes>;
    isPending = 0;
    messages = RLMArray <0x1702f1f00> (
        [0] MessageRow {
            id = 1;
            message = cyka blyat idi nahuiy.;
            state = -1;
            senderID = 2;
            receiverID = 1;
            remoteID = 35;
            burnTime = 0;
            timestamp = 1481819648;
            filePath = ;
        },
        [1] MessageRow {
            id = 2;
            message = test message;
            state = -1;
            senderID = 2;
            receiverID = 1;
            remoteID = 36;
            burnTime = 0;
            timestamp = 1481819776;
            filePath = ;
        }
    );
}) Optional(RealmSwift.Realm)
```

Comment: Does this happen when you have the app open or when you reopen the app? Please also add the code where you create and save the file.

Comment: Can you share your code around instantiate Realm instance and saving objects to the realm?

Comment: @Yannick This happens when I reopen the app, however the file seems to be existing and then removed at random intervals. For instance a write to the friend list at first seems to show an existing file, while later saving messages results in a file no longer being able to be found

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi https://www.dropbox.com/s/tmovpbxzfnplrgs/Screenshot%202016-12-15%2016.39.08.png?dl=0

Comment: @AntwanvanHoudt Could you update your post instead screenshot? Also, can you show details of `receiver.row` and definition of `MessageRow`.

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi done the update, receiver is a User instance, which contains User row much like Message and MessageRow is.

Comment: @AntwanvanHoudt Still unclear for me. More code needed. `receiver.row` and `author.row` is saved to Realm? Can you show a output of `print(receiver.row.realm)` and `print(author.row)`? What is `Database.default.realm` implementation? Can you show the whole code of `Database`?

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi attached output, I don't know if I should paste the entire Database.swift but it pretty much is just a wrapper around Configuring realm and creating a single instance accessed through the singleton using "Database.default.realm". The code above, the config, is what is used to create the realm instance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130725/discussion-between-kishikawa-katsumi-and-antwan-van-houdt).